# Mongodb pass code to be executed on the server during query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I am using [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) and what I am trying to do is query a collection, and receive well *filtered* and *ordered* and *projected* result. Sadly the logic I want to implement is complex and even if we assume that it is possible to use [db.collection.aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) it will result in long, complex, hard to read aggregate descriptor, which I believe in most cases is unwanted.

So I was thinking - Mongodb understands javascript, therefor most likely I can pass a javascript function during the query itself, expecting that my mongo server will make the query, run the provided function passing the query result to it, then return the final result to me. Something like:

`db.collection.find(myQuery, serverCallback).toArray(function(err, db) { ... });`

Sadly it seems this is impossible. Investigating further I reached [stored javascript](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) and understood that I can define that serverCallback on the server instead of passing it. Which is good, but seems messy and wrong to me. So basically this is the reason, why i decided to ask here if someone with better mongodb experience can argument this approach.

**[My understandings]**

I beleive that not every case of filtering, aggregating, etc. can be achieved with db.collection.aggregate, which is pretty normal. For all the cases that need special way of filtering the query result, we have two options - to define stored javascript that we execute on the query result on the mongo server, or to fetch the information from the server and do the processing/filtering/etc. in the client.

- If we choose to define stored javascript, it is very likely that we will define some project specific logic into the mongo server. I think that the project specifics should always belong to the project code instead of the database. That way we can version them with git and easily access them if we want to change them.
- If we choose to apply the aggregation logic after the query we loose the capability to choose who will make the calculations - the server or the client. Which may be an opinion that we want to have.

**[My question]**

What is the reasoning behind not allowing serverCallback to be provided during the query? I believe that there must be reasons that I do not understand here.

**[Edits]**

First I want to say that I have resolve my problem and as it was way too complex to explain it easily. I will prefer to stick to something easier to explain and understand. I believe [this](http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html) example of MongoDB stored javascript provides great example so lets use it. Basically what i tried to ask above was is there a way to pass this sum function during ***db.collection.find*** (and why there isn't any). Something like this:

```
function sum(queryResultAsArray) {
    //Do whatever we want with queryResultAsArray
    //For the example we filter result rows with x + y == 6;
    return queryResultAsArray.filter(function(row) {
        return row.x + row.y == 6
    });
}
db.test.find({}, queryResultAsArray);
```

And this to be equal to the examples:

```
db.test.find({$where: "sum(this.x, this.y) == 6"});
```

For reasoning on why would one can prefer passing function rather than stored javascript see the original post.

Comment: Really not that clear what the actual question is here. You might have perhaps made a clearer point by instead demonstrating something you are trying to do and what you would expect to happen. You sort of need to understand a lot of us have been using this for years, and for some pretty big projects. So there are some pretty big minds behind the way things are done. Perhaps we can show you a better direction if you instead show us what you want to achieve.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry for the late response, I tried to add a clarification edit regarding you comment.

Comment: I would avise dropping the "way too complex" line and actually present what you need to do instead. We get questions with "complex query" in them all of the time. 99% of them get pointed to an existing simple solution. So you really need to show what you actually intend and someone can show you what to do instead. But it won't be server JavaScript execution.